# Como faço para recuperar os filtros de uma query?

Tags: c#, query, linq

Olá. É possível descobrir quais filtros, ordenadores, etc, foram utilizados em uma query?

Exemplo:

```
public class Program
{
    class Produto
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Nome;

        public Produto(int id, string nome)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Nome = nome;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Produto> produtos = new List<Produto>();
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1, "Arroz"));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(2, "Feijão"));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(3, "Trigo"));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(4, "Batata"));

        var query = from produto in produtos
                 where produto.Id < 3
                 select produto;
    }
}
```

No caso, o que eu preciso é que *query* me retorne que seu filtro é "id < 3"

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possivel.

Assim:

```
var query = (from produto in produtos
             where produto.Id < 3).AsQueryable();
var predicado = query.Expression;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Implementei esse código, mas não consigo extrair mais nada de Expression. Ele apenas disponibiliza pra mim os seguintes métodos:
> CanReduce, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, NodeType, Reduce, ReduceAndCheck, ReduceExtension e ToString.

Comment: Então, trabalhar com a `Expression` merece outra pergunta.

Comment: Isso nao vai funcionar. `produtos` é uma `List<T>`, e portanto, `from x in produtos` vai ser compilado como `Enumerable.Select(produtos, x => ...)`. O método [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) aceita um delegate, e não uma expressão. Logo, a expressão lambda vai ser convertida para um delegate - e depois dessa conversão é impossível recuperar a expression tree original.