# Como faço para extrair os valores de uma Expression?

Tags: c#, query, linq, expressões-lambda

Olá. É possível extrair de uma Expression quais filtros, ordenadores, etc, foram utilizados em uma query?

Exemplo:

```
public class Program
{
    class Produto
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Nome;

        public Produto(int id, string nome)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Nome = nome;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Produto> produtos = new List<Produto>();
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1, "Arroz"));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(2, "Feijão"));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(3, "Trigo"));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(4, "Batata"));

        var expression = (from produto in produtos
                          where produto.Id < 3
                          select produto).AsQueryable().Expression;
    }
}
```

No caso, o que eu preciso é extrair de expression que o filtro utilizado foi *Id < 3*

Comment: Esse filtro utilizado é uma lógica de negócio. Mesmo se comparar o restultado da query com o domínio total dos dados você não vai ter como garantir o filtro utilizado, pois mais de um cenário de filtro pode provocar o mesmo resultado. Um exemplo é o resultado igual entre `Id > 3` e `Nome.EndsWith("a")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Como te falei na pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91011/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-recuperar-os-filtros-de-uma-query), [há vários tipos de `Expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx), o que exige que você coloque uma lógica adicional para recuperar os valores do seu filtro.

Normalmente, este parâmetro `Expression` é uma [`BinaryExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.aspx). Seus componentes podem ser obtidos da seguinte forma:

```
var expression = meuQueryable.Expression as BinaryExpression;
```

`BinaryExpressions` normalmente possuem `Left` e `Right` que, por sua vez, também são `Expressions`. Um código que uso para testar que tipo de expressão é `Left` e `Right` (não é muito bom, estou aperfeiçoando ainda) é o seguinte:

```
            switch (expression.Left.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression":
                case "System.Linq.Expressions.MethodBinaryExpression":
                    valorFinalEsquerdo = Condicao(expression.Left);
                    break;
                case "System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression":
                    var body2 = expression.Left as UnaryExpression;

                    if (body2 != null)
                    {
                        var left2 = body2.Operand as MemberExpression;
                        if (left2 != null)
                        {
                            var teste = ReflectionUtils.ExtrairAtributoColumnDeMember(left2.Member);
                            valorFinalEsquerdo = teste.Name;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    var left = expression.Left as MemberExpression;
                    if (left != null)
                    {
                        var teste = ReflectionUtils.ExtrairAtributoColumnDeMember(left.Member);
                        valorFinalEsquerdo = teste.Name;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            switch (expression.Right.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "System.Linq.Expressions.MethodBinaryExpression":
                    valorFinalDireito = Condicao(expression.Right);
                    break;
                case "System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression":
                        var right2 = expression.Right as MemberExpression;
                        if (right2 != null)
                        {
                            valorFinalDireito = AvaliarExpressao(right2);
                        }

                    break;
                default:
                    var right = expression.Right as ConstantExpression;
                    if (right != null)
                    {
                        valorFinalDireito = right.Value;
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

O código faz parte de uma função chamada `Condicao`, que chamo recursivamente. Os valores são obtidos dentro de `valorFinalDireito` e `valorFinalEsquerdo`.

Comment: Obrigado. Estou estudando essa solução.